# Слушатель изменения окна JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize

Существует ли слушатель изменения размера окна `jframe`?

Если есть, то можно хоть самый маленький пример?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) является [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) - можно воспользоваться методом [addContainerListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addContainerListener-java.awt.event.ContainerListener-), и лучше использовать [ComponentAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html), чтобы не переопределять все события. Код будет что-то типа:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");    
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {  
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
            // Сделать что-то
        }
});
```

Также можете посмотреть [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106367/listen-to-jframe-resize-events-as-the-user-drags-their-mouse) и ответы к нему на en.SO.